# Stream a list of maps with a condition

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have a list that looks like this:

```
List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps;
```

From this list, i want to extract only a few maps based on a given condition. Normally, I would write it like this:

```
for(Map m : listOfMaps) { 
   if(m.get("someValue").equals("someOtherValue")) {
          resultMap.put(m.get("a"), m.get("b"))
     }
}
```

I would like to write this using java8 streams.

Comment: `Map<String, String> resultMap = 
        listOfMaps.stream().filter(m -> m.get("someValue").equals("someOtherValue")).collect(toMap(m -> m.get("a"), m -> m.get("b")));`

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty straightforwardly rewrite your loop as a stream operation.

```
listOfMaps.stream()
   .filter(m -> m.get("someValue").equals("someOtherValue"))
   .forEach(m -> resultMap.put(m.get("a"), m.get("b")));
```

Not sure particularly what it gets you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could collect all results to a new map:

```
Map<String, String> resultMap = listOfMaps.stream()
    .filter(m -> "someOtherValue".equals(m.get("someValue")))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        m -> m.get("a"),
        m -> m.get("b")));
```